# How to perform equal rationing in Linear Programming using Python library PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming

I'll explain my question with the help of following example.

In this problem, I'm having 4 Players having the quantities shown in quantity, and prices shown in price. I also have estimated quantity as estimate. The goal is to fulfil estimated quantity using the available quantities with four Players. And selection policy is such that, Players having the lower prices will be given priority to supply quantities.

```
price = [140, 50, 80, 60]

quantity = [100, 150, 200, 400]

estimate = 400
```

So, for this question, quantity supplied by each of the player is,

```
supply = [0, 150, 0, 250]
```

This is just a simple example, actual size of the array is more than this. I'm using PuLP library of Python to solve this Linear Programming question.

But the problem is when all the prices are equal, then it gives answer based on the index, means player at index0 will supply first, then player at index1 and so on. But, my actual requirement is to divide the estimated quantity between all the player equally in equal pricing scenario. See the example,

```
price = [60, 60, 60, 60]

quantity = [100, 150, 200, 400]

estimate = 400
```

Output is,

```
supply = [100 , 150, 150, 0]
```

And my requirement is,

```
supply = [100, 100, 100, 100]
```

So, my question is, how to solve equal rationing problem ?

Comment: Be careful with ```But the problem is when all the prices are equal, then it gives answer based on the index, means player at index0 will supply first, then player at index1 and so on```. This is dependent on the solver-design and while this should be deterministic, it might change from solver-version to solver-version!

Comment: Counting the number of variables that are equal requires extra binary variables. You'll end up with a MIP model.

Comment: Thank for your suggestions and answer @sascha.

Comment: Thank you @erwin. I'll grateful if you can share some resources about MIP model.

Comment: There are tons of books about Mixed Integer Programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas:

#### LP

Introduce a weighted penalty-component to the objective which is the sum of all pairwise-differences (absolute-value!) of supply-vars.

Pros:

- can be formulated as LP

Cons:

- weight of this penalty is problem-dependent and needs to be tuned!
- exponential growth in number of pairs (in regards to #supplies)

  - results in auxiliary-variables and constraints
  - given a fast formulation, the solver will start to struggle with `N >> 100` (e.g. 10 seconds solve-time for `N=150`; depends on *bigM*)
- needs absolute-value re-formulation ([lpsolve docs](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/absolute.htm))

  - needs to be done manually in pulp

#### SOCP

Introduce a weighted penalty-component to the objective which is the euclidean-norm of the supply-vars.

Pros:

- no exponential growth of vars / constraints

Cons:

- weight of this penalty is problem-dependent and needs to be tuned!
- not linear anymore: SOCP-solver needed (which are less robust)
- needs a norm-formulation (but this is very natural if one has access to an SOCP-solver)

I'm not using much pulp and will show both approaches **conceptionally** (bigM not tuned; slow formulation) using [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org), which automatically gives us *abs* and *norm* functions (reformulations).

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx
from itertools import combinations
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=6)

# price = np.array([140, 50, 80, 60])
# quantity = np.array([100, 150, 200, 400])

price = np.array([60, 60, 60, 60])
quantity = np.array([100, 150, 200, 400])

estimate = 400

# LP approach
def solve_lp(penalty=True):
    bigM = 1e-3

    N = len(price)
    pairs = list(combinations(range(N), 2))

    x = cvx.Variable(N)
    constraints = [x >= 0,
                   cvx.sum_entries(x) >= estimate,
                   x <= quantity]
    obj_costs = price * x
    obj_penalty = sum([cvx.abs(x[a] - x[b]) for (a,b) in pairs])
    objective = obj_costs + bigM * float(penalty) * obj_penalty

    problem = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(objective), constraints)
    problem.solve(solver='CBC')  # Warning: solver not shipped by default
                                 #          same solver as shipped by pulp
                                 #          = Clp/Cbc
    print(problem.status)
    print(problem.value)
    print(x.value.T)

# QP approach
def solve_socp(penalty=True):
    bigM = 1e-3

    N = len(price)
    est_avg = estimate / N

    x = cvx.Variable(N)
    constraints = [x >= 0,
                   cvx.sum_entries(x) >= estimate,
                   x <= quantity]
    obj_costs = price * x
    obj_penalty = cvx.norm(x - est_avg)
    objective = obj_costs + bigM * float(penalty) * obj_penalty

    problem = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(objective), constraints)
    problem.solve(solver='ECOS')
    print(problem.status)
    print(problem.value)
    print(x.value.T)

print('LP a')
solve_lp(penalty=False)
print('LP b')
solve_lp(penalty=True)
print('SOCP a')
solve_socp(penalty=False)
print('SOCP b')
solve_socp(penalty=True)
```

#### Output

```
LP a
optimal
24000.0
[[100. 100. 200.   0.]]
LP b
optimal
24000.0
[[100. 100. 100. 100.]]
SOCP a
optimal
24000.000032013406
[[ 44.92762   69.401923  93.878797 191.791661]]
SOCP b
optimal
24000.000001071123
[[ 99.999423  99.999973  99.999959 100.000645]]
```

Remark: the SOCP is solved by an interior-point method, which approximates the solution (in theory: as accurate as wanted). Therefore values are not exactly 100.